# JPA / Hibernate - @OrderBy random

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have JpaRepository class and entities with OneToMany unidirectional relationship. I tried to use the @OrderBy annotation but it didn't work. I need the list items to be in random order.

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
@OrderBy("function('RAND')")
private List<Bar> bars;

}
```

Comment: 'I need the list items to be in random order' - could you please elaborate on that? Are you expecting to see a different order every time you fetch the entity, or do you simply want an arbitrary order, different from the one in which the children have been inserted?

Comment: @crizzis, it should be different every time I fetch the entity.

Comment: In such case, I believe it will be very hard if not impossible. You're better off scrambling the list in memory *after* loading the entity TBH

Comment: If you really insist on doing it in the DB, you *might* be able to use Hibernate's [`@JoinFormula`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/JoinFormula.html), which should allow you to use arbitrary SQL to fetch the associated list. Randomizing the list in memory will likely be much more performant, though

Comment: @crizzis Ok, thanks. I'll randomize it in memory then.